# Send a POST to a HTTPS - Logic Issue

Tags: java, http, post, stored-procedures, https

Anyone knows why i get this error. I am trying to send a POST request, and here's the error message that i get.

Server response:

```
Error while dispatching hrxml [ Server was unable to process request. --> Procedure or function 'sp__LogMessage' expects parameter '@pi_ClientID', which was not supplied.   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
   at DispatchService.HRISMessageRouter.MessageRouter.Route(String HRXML)
   at DispatchService.DispatchMessage.Dispatch(String HRXML)]
```

My Code :

```
URL link = new URL("https://example.com/example.asp"); 
        HttpsURLConnection com = (HttpsURLConnection) link.openConnection();
                  String l;

        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
con.setDoInput(true); 
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        con.setRequestProperty("name", "rrrrr");
        con.setRequestProperty("pwd", "ffff");

        OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream();

        os.flush();

        InputStream is = con.getInputStream();

        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

          StringBuffer r = new StringBuffer(); 

          while((l = rd.readLine()) != null) {

            r.append(l);

            r.append('\r');

          }

          rd.close();

          System.out.println("out "+ r.toString());
```

I have tried debugging the code etc, but still unable to find a possible reason to why this hapend . Can anyone help me to figure out the reason and a possible solution for this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from the stacktrace:

1. Your application is talking to a SOAP service
2. The SOAP service is expecting an (XML encoded) request which includes a parameter that doesn't exist.

But this doesn't mesh with what you client code is doing.  In fact, you are sending a POST request with parameters, and that will turn into a request body which is probably encoded as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` ... not XML.  That ain't going to work.

Comment: Do you mena i should include this line `con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", 
             "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");` ?

Can you please show me an example which will explain your scenario ?

Comment: Adding a `Content-type` header probably won't help.  The request probably already has one.  You need to find out what the server actually expects you to send ... and send that.

Answer (score 2):

The error message is:

> Server was unable to process request. --> Procedure or function 'sp__LogMessage' expects parameter '@pi_ClientID', which was not supplied.

This looks like a SQL Stored Procedure on the server.  Check to make sure that a client ID is being supplied to it.

Comment: What do you mean supply client IT to it. Should i pass the client ID from my code to the server ? some thing like this `con.setRequestProperty("ID", "someID");` ?

Comment: You need to make sure that your call is fulfilling the contract of the API you're sending the POST request to.  If that checks out, you'll need to see if there's a problem on the server side preventing the stored procedure from getting the necessary client id.  If you don't have access to the server, you may be out of luck.

Comment: Is there any simulator i could use to test if the web service is working ? Like for example, when i type the parameters and the simulator sends a POST to check if the service works ?